# Wait for a promise before launching the postback in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to implement v3 recaptcha on my asp.net webforms page.

The main problem is that I believe that grecaptcha.ready is asynchronous as the page immediately postbacks and does not wait for the client event to finish.

How can I make the postback wait for grecaptcha.ready and grecaptcha.execute?

Front code:

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=key"></script>
     <script>
         function onbtnRegistrazioneClick(e) {  
        
             return grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                 grecaptcha.execute('key', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
                     console.log(token);
                     document.getElementById("gRecaptchaResponse").value = token;
                    
                 });
             });
            
         }
     </script>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegistrazioneCliente" CssClass="btnGenerico" Text='<%$ Resources:btnRegistratiText%>' ValidationGroup="NewUtente" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="onbtnRegistrazioneClick(event);"></asp:Button>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="gRecaptchaResponse" name="gRecaptchaResponse" />
```

Back Code:

```
 Public Sub btnRegistrazioneCliente_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrazioneCliente.Click 'btnRegistrazioneCliente.ServerClick '
        If Me.IsValid Then 

            Dim gRecaptchaResponse As String = Request.Form("gRecaptchaResponse")
            Dim isCaptchaValid As Boolean = Globals.Security.ReCaptchaV3.Validate(gRecaptchaResponse)
        '...

        else

        '...

        end if 

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
__doPostBack('<%=btnRegistrazioneCliente.UniqueID%>', 'OnClick');   

 <script>
         function onbtnRegistrazioneClick(e) {  
        
             return grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                 grecaptcha.execute('6Ld2D1MbAAAAAMwnZ4iN1p1G9K7YQWdQW84nNQjv', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
                 
                     document.getElementById("gRecaptchaResponse").value = token;
                     __doPostBack('<%=btnRegistrazioneCliente.UniqueID%>', 'OnClick');
                 });
             });
            
         }
     </script>
```